# Find the last 2 digits of (2007^2006 + 2006^2007 + 6)^2018?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I solved it using unit of LTD (last 2 digits) $LTD(2006^{2007}) = 36$

and $LTD(2007^{2006}) = 49$ using cyclicity of $07=(91)^{2018}$

but I wasn't able to solve it further